# Why is "df.grouby" reducing some Columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Data Frame with 16 columns and when i group it by one of the columns it reduces the size of the Data Frame to 12 columns

```
def update_centroids(cluster, k): 
   df["Cluster"] = cluster     
   display(df)     
   display(df.groupby("Cluster").mean().shape)    
   return df.groupby("Cluster").mean()
```

This is the "df"
[image]

This is what the function returns
[image]

It just removes the cloumn "WindGustDir", "WindDir9am" & "WindDir3pm"

I can't think of anything that would cause that and I can't seem to find anything online.

Sample Data (df)

```
{'MinTemp': {0: 0.11720244784576628,
  1: -0.8427745726259455,
  2: 0.03720436280645697,
  3: -0.5547814664844322,
  4: 0.7731867451681026},
 'MaxTemp': {0: -0.10786029175347862,
  1: 0.20733745161878284,
  2: 0.29330047253849006,
  3: 0.6228253860640358,
  4: 1.2388937026552729},
 'Rainfall': {0: -0.20728093808218293,
  1: -0.2769572340371439,
  2: -0.2769572340371439,
  3: -0.2769572340371439,
  4: -0.16083007411220893},
 'WindGustDir': {0: 1.0108491579487748,
  1: 1.2354908672839122,
  2: 0.7862074486136377,
  3: -1.2355679354025977,
  4: 1.0108491579487748},
 'WindGustSpeed': {0: 0.24007558342699453,
  1: 0.24007558342699453,
  2: 0.390124802975703,
  3: -1.2604166120600901,
  4: 0.015001754103931822},
 'WindDir9am': {0: 1.0468595036148063,
  1: 1.6948858890138538,
  2: 1.0468595036148063,
  3: -0.24919326718328894,
  4: -0.8972196525823365},
 'WindDir3pm': {0: 1.2126203373471025,
  1: 0.764386964628212,
  2: 0.764386964628212,
  3: -0.8044298398879051,
  4: 1.4367370237065478},
 'WindSpeed9am': {0: 0.5756272310362935,
  1: -1.3396174328344796,
  2: 0.45592443954437023,
  3: -0.5016978923910164,
  4: -0.9805090583587096},
 'WindSpeed3pm': {0: 0.5236467885906614,
  1: 0.29063908419611084,
  2: 0.7566544929852119,
  3: -1.2239109943684676,
  4: 0.057631379801560294},
 'Humidity9am': {0: 0.18973417158101255,
  1: -1.2387396584055541,
  2: -1.556178287291458,
  3: -1.1858332202579036,
  4: 0.7717049912051694},
 'Humidity3pm': {0: -1.381454000080091,
  1: -1.2369929482683248,
  2: -0.9962245285820479,
  3: -1.6703761037036233,
  4: -0.8517634767702817},
 'Pressure9am': {0: -1.3829003897707315,
  1: -0.9704973422317451,
  2: -1.3971211845134583,
  3: 0.024958289758919134,
  4: -0.9420557527463073},
 'Pressure3pm': {0: -1.142657774670493,
  1: -1.0420314949852805,
  2: -0.9126548496756962,
  3: -0.32327235437655133,
  4: -1.3007847856044166},
 'Temp9am': {0: -0.08857174739799159,
  1: -0.0413389204605655,
  2: 0.5569435540801637,
  3: 0.1003595603517128,
  4: 0.0531267334142867},
 'Temp3pm': {0: -0.04739593761083206,
  1: 0.318392868036414,
  2: 0.1574457935516255,
  3: 0.6402870170059903,
  4: 1.1084966882344651},
 'Cluster': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your sample data for df, it looks like `df.groupby("Cluster").mean()` does not remove any columns.

One possible explanation: using `groupby().mean()` on non-numeric types will cause the column to be removed entirely. If you have a large dataset that you are importing from a file or something, is it possible that there are non-numeric data types?

If, for example, you are reading a csv file using `pd.read_csv()`, and there are cells that read "NULL", they may be parsed as strings instead of numeric values. One option to find rows with non-numeric values is to use:

```
import numpy as np
df[~df.applymap(np.isreal).all(1)]
```

Comment: I Tried it out it returns an empty data frame